# How to download files in ftp using phpstorm

Tags: ftp, phpstorm

I recently started connecting to my server using PHPStrom, and I can send files(upload) to the server just fine, but after having searched and searched, I can not find a way to download files from server. Is this feature not possible in PHPStorm?

Comment: Have you set up a mapping between your local and remote folders?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I don't know what that means, but I am able to upload files to my server without any problems

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To seamlessly up- and download files to and from your server, you're going to want to set up a deployment configuration with a **mapping** between a local and a remote folder. Here is how.

1. Open the deployment configuration window by selecting **Tools** → **Deployment** → **Configuration...** from the menu.

   [image]
2. If you haven't already created a deployment connection, create one one. I have already created one here and switched the **Mappings** tab.

   [image]

   The **Deployment path on server** is the location on the server (relative to the **Root path** set up for the connection) where your project files are located.
3. In the **Remote Host** panel, you'll now be able to download files to your project folder.

   [image]

   Additionally, you can also download the server version of a file, by using the options available under the **Deployment** submenu in the context menu in the Project panel.

Comment: Super answer. Although, I am only able to download the file then change it and then upload it back again. But, in I can't seem to edit it directly or directly modify it. It would be nice if you could shed some lights on that one.

Comment: @ANW: You can't really directly edit a file on the remote host. You can set PHPStorm up to automatically sync a file to the remote host when you save though. In Settings, under Deployment -> Options, check the setting **Upload changed files automatically to the default server**. You can set it to automatically upload on Ctrl+S. But be sure to mark a server as the default server in your deployment settings. There's a **Mark as default** button above the deployment configuration list.

Comment: Where is Remote Host panel?

Comment: @JulianMoreno Sorry, I don't use WebStorm anymore and can't look it up for you.